# path.join error in Electron's ipcRenderer

Tags: electron, ipcrenderer

I am creating a Windows app using Electron, React, and Vite.
Currently I'm just learning it.

In my `App.jsx` file, when I am importing `ipcRenderer` as `import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";`; I am getting an error as shown in the image below.

[image]

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: seems like that warning is giving you the answer. Have you clicked on that link?

Comment: Yes, I have opened the link. But unable to understand that what to do.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but found [this solution](https://dev.to/0xbf/vite-module-path-has-been-externalized-for-browser-compatibility-2bo6)

Comment: or look here https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9200

Answer (score 0):

I use `require` to fix it.

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
```